# My stored Function has disappeared, presumably at the end of my RazorSQL session

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix

I was using RazorSQL's live session window to create and edit several stored procedures.

I've since disconnected from the database, and reconnected, and now those procedures have disappeared.

Presumably I'm screwing up, here, but I'm using a login which has permission to create these procedures and while I'm still connected the first time I can actually connect in and execute the stored procedures, so I know they're at least there at that point.

What more do I have to do in RazorSQL than write a working "CREATE FUNCTION" block in order to cause the function to become persistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Informix, almost all SQL statements, both DDL and DML, are subject to transactions (the exceptions are CREATE DATABASE, DROP DATABASE and RENAME DATABASE).

There are several types of database in Informix - the key distinction for the current purpose is between 'MODE ANSI' and 'logged' and 'unlogged' databases.

- A MODE ANSI database always starts a transaction when you execute a statement such as CREATE FUNCTION, and the transaction continues until you COMMIT [WORK], ROLLBACK [WORK] or exit the session (which is equivalent to ROLLBACK).
- A logged database supports transactions, but each statement is a self-contained transaction  unless you explicitly start a transaction with BEGIN [WORK].  Effectively, AutoCommit applies until you execute BEGIN WORK.
- An unlogged database does not support transactions; each statement is more or less a self-contained transaction, with no mechanism to override this behaviour.

It seems to me that the most likely explanation of what you saw is:

- You (or RazorSQL) started a transaction (explicitly with BEGIN WORK, or implicitly in a MODE ANSI database) and exited before committing the transaction, so the effects were rolled back.

Comment: So transactions will actually roll back the creation of a stored procedure which has been executed? Crikey...

Comment: @Frosty840 - That's not so surprising, a transaction allows you to commit or rollback the SQL commands executed against your database. As far as the DB is concerned commands to insert/change data are no different to create/drop commands.

Comment: @Frosty840: yes - you can do: `BEGIN; DROP TABLE; CREATE TABLE; LOAD TABLE; ROLLBACK;` and everything is as before.